Forecasting time series using simulations
Suppose we have a stationary time series $x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{T}$. Goal is to forecast up to $T+h$, i.e., forecast $x_{T+1}, x_{T+2}, ..., x_{T+h}$.
Forecasting methodology:

Using econometric techniques one can try to fit a model, which describes the data generating process of $\{x\}_{t}$ (e.g., ARIMA or other model).
Then, having estimated parameters of the model one can simulate using forward Monte Carlo technique many paths up to $T+h$.
Using simulated paths, one can construct an empirical PDF for each point in time in the future,  i.e., $f_{T+1}(x), f_{T+2}(x), ..., f_{T+h}(x)$.
As a forecast for  $x_{T+1}, x_{T+2}, ..., x_{T+h}$, take mean of $f_{T+1}(x), f_{T+2}(x), ..., f_{T+h}(x)$, respectively.

Question: Is this kind of method acceptable or widely used for stationary process forecasting? What are the main problems and assumptions of this method? Also, I assume that forecasts will be the same as the current value, i.e., $E(x_{T+i}|x_T)=x_{t}$ for any $i$. Is this assumption correct?

Deciding how to simulate the paths might give you everything you need, even if you never wind up doing the simulation. For example, if you run a regression where the assumed conditional distribution is Gaussian with a mean equal to the fitted value and variance related to the sum of squared residuals, you already know everything you would know about this assumed distribution, even if you never run something like rnorm(N, yhat[i], sse/(n-p)) in R or np.random.normal(yhat[i], sse/(n-p), N) in Python to draw possible values from that distribution. Could you please clarify what you want to do?

The goal is to construct a forecasts' PDFs using above described methodology. And the question is whether that method makes sense or not.

But how do you create those (different) paths?

From the estimated model (steps 2 and 3 above).

But the model makes one point estimate per time step, right?

It could be extended to $h>1$ horizon recursively using ARIMA structure.

If you just want an expectation forecast (there are others!), then you can use closed form expressions in ARIMA, no simulation necessary. Many other methods will also let you directly forecast the expectation.
Simulations often do make sense, e.g., if you use some kind of ML approach, especially if you are interested in the full predictive density.
And no, the expectation forecast is not necessarily constant, not even in ARIMA. You can have all kinds of dynamics that make for changing forecasts, from seasonality to predictors.

Your point is a good one -- if one has estimated model, then forecast and its confidence interval can be derived. Then what is the point to use MC?

There are situations where there is no closed form for the conditional expectation forecast, e.g., if you are using a model that does not estimate this functional at all, but e.g., outputs a predictive density directly. In this situation, simulations may be your best bet. Alternatively, we may be interested in other functionals than the expectation, like a quantile, and while our model may output the expectation, it may do so non-parametrically.

(Incidentally, I assume you mean a prediction interval, not a confidence interval; there is a difference).

I see, thank you! Yes, it was a typo -- should be prediction interval.
